# Getting a value from a Class Object in Python based on User Input

Tags: python-3.x, class

so I'm in the process of learning Python, so forgive any naivety.

I'm doing some practice on Classes - and I'm making it so that when a user input their car - it looks for instantiated objects and then returns the price.

I get it to work okay for "BMW" - but when I try Ferrari - it only return the price for the BMW (20k). I'm thinking it is something not right with the price_check function part of the code.

Please could you provide some guidance here? Code below:

```
class Car:
   car_list = []

   def __init__(self, make, model, price):
       self.make = make
       self.model = model
       self.price = price

       self.car_list.append(self)

#this is the part of the code that i'm stuck with

   def price_check(self):
       for i in Car.car_list:
           if New_Car.make == self.make:
               return i.price
        else:
            print("Not available")


 BMW = Car('BMW', '1 Series', "£20,000")
 Ferrari = Car('Ferrari', 'Italia', "£90,000")

New_Car = Car(
      input("What is make of your car? "), input("What is the model? "), "")

 print("The cost of this car is: ", New_Car.price_check())
```

So essentially, I want it to return the price of the Ferrari if that's what the user typed.

Thanks in advance. And, sorry for any incorrect formatting, etc...

Comment: @Jarvis - Thank you kindly - it worked! I totally get it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I agree with the comments made by @Jarvis regarding errors in your code, I would also add that in Cars init the price is a required variable and should cause an error on instantiation.  In addition, in price_check, since the new_car instance has already been added to the list, price_check will also examine that entry and either find None or 0 price, so will never get to the "No Price Available" return.  Here's how I would implement the Class

```
class Car:
    car_list = []
    
    def __init__(self, make, model, price=None):  #makes providing price optional
        self._make = make
        self._model = model
        self._price = price
        Car.car_list.append(self)
        
    @property
    def make(self):
        return self._make
    
    @property
    def model(self):
        return self._model
    
    @property
    def price(self):
        return self._price
    
    @price.setter
    def price(self, val):
        self._price = val
        
    def price_check(self):
        for i in Car.car_list:
            if i != self and self.make == i.make and self.model == i.model:
                return i.price
        return "Not available"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues, first you need to append to the `list` not bound to your `instance` but the one bound to your `class` as a class-attribute:

```
def __init__(self, make, model, price):
   self.make = make
   self.model = model
   self.price = price

   # use the 'class' rather than the 'instance', you need to modify a class-attribute
   Car.car_list.append(self)
```

Second, your issue in price check

```
def price_check(self):
   for i in Car.car_list:
       # you need to compare self's make with 'i.make' (elements in list)
       if self.make == i.make:
           return i.price
       else:
           print("Not available")
```